# What is the regex to match a digit character from any language?

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode, digit

Given an input that contains non-Latin "digit" characters, i.e. not one of 0-9, such as

```
String input = "3\u0e53\u0969"; // i.e. "3๓३"
```

which is made up of the characters:

- 3
- [๓](https://codepoints.net/U+0E53?lang=en) the Thai character for 3
- [३](https://codepoints.net/U+0E53?lang=en) an Indian dialect character for 3

what regex matches this, requiring that all the characters be "digits"?

ie, what must `regex` be in the following snippet for `matches()` to return `true`?

```
"3๓३".matches(regex)
```